# Any way to verify user password from PL/PGSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I need to verify user password, but this user may be "local" (with `md5` method in `pg_hba.conf`) or LDAP user. This works fine and "local" and LDAP users can login, but I need to verify their password in PL/PGSQL in some function. Is it possible? To call some Postgres system function like `verify_login(userName TEXT, userPassword TEXT)` which returns `BOOLEAN` and it knows how to check the password of the user when it is local/LDAP/etc. user.

PS. Little bit strange idea, but it's the requirement of my task.

Answer (score 1):

I did it as:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION login(auid TEXT, password TEXT, dbhost TEXT DEFAULT NULL) RETURNS ...
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS
$$
DECLARE
  rec RECORD;
  conn_str TEXT;
  dbname TEXT;
  conn_name TEXT;
  failed BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
  SELECT u.uid AS role,u.my_role,u.display_name INTO rec FROM ldap_users u
    WHERE u.uid=auid AND u.my_role IS NOT NULL;

  IF NOT FOUND THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'User not permitted to access TV'
      USING HINT='No such user or it is not allowed to access TV';
  END IF;

  IF dbhost IS NULL THEN
    dbhost := FORMAT('%s', INET_SERVER_ADDR());
  END IF;

  dbname := CURRENT_DATABASE();
  conn_str = 'host=' || dbhost || ' dbname=' || dbname || ' user=' || auid || ' password=' || password;
  conn_name := FORMAT('conn_%s', RANDOM());

  BEGIN
    PERFORM dblink_connect(conn_name, conn_str);
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN failed := TRUE;
  END;

  BEGIN
    PERFORM dblink_disconnect(conn_name);
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
  END;

  IF failed THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'User failed to login to the DB'
      USING HINT='It seems the password is wrong';
  ELSE
    ...
    RETURN ...
  END IF;

END;
$$;
```

Specific things are replaced with `...` - they are not related to the question.
To use it you need `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS dblink;` to enable the `dblink` extension.

This `login()` function verifies the password of the user by connecting to itself (to the current host (if `dbhost` is `NULL`) and to the current database.

It was tested and I use it but it works fine only if the host has just one IP. Otherwise, it's not clean which IP will be returned from the `INET_SERVER_ADDR()`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer originally added to the question by the author:

I found only `dblink_connect()` and it seems to work.